# python XML parsing issue with minidom

Tags: python, xml

Can someone tell me what is the best method to parse the xml doc..

My XML file looks like below. The XML tags are not consistent across every block and  my script is failing because it cant find the key in all the iterations. Im using minidom

```
<Header version=test>
  <pool name="A">
     <pooltier name="1"></pooltier>
     <pooltier name="2"></pooltier>
     <pooltier name="3"></pooltier>
  </pool>
  <pool name="B">
     <pooltier name="1"></pooltier>
     <pooltier name="2"></pooltier>
     <pooltier name="3"></pooltier>
  </pool>
     <pool name="C">"No PoolTier Here"
  </pool>
</Header>
```

Not all the "pool" has "pooltier"

Snippet from my code:

```
pools = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Pool')
    for poolname in pools:
        print(poolname.attributes['name'].value)
        print(poolname.attributes['poolID'].value)
        poolnam = poolname.attributes['name'].value
        poolnum = poolname.attributes['poolID'].value
        pooluse = poolname.attributes['usageRate'].value

        pooltiers = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PoolTier')
        print(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PoolTier'))
        for tiername in pooltiers:
            Tid = tiername.attributes['tierID'].value
            capKB = tiername.attributes['capacityInKB'].value
            FreeKB = tiername.attributes['freeCapacityInKB'].value
            Usage = tiername.attributes['usageRate'].value
            raid = tiername.attributes['raidLevel'].value
            rpmval = tiername.attributes['rpm'].value
            dtype = tiername.attributes['diskType'].value
            print(tiername.attributes['tierID'].value)
            #print(tiername.attributes['capacityInKB'].value)
            #print(tiername.attributes['freeCapacityInKB'].value)
            #print(tiername.attributes['usageRate'].value)
            #print(tiername.attributes['raidLevel'].value)
            #print(tiername.attributes['rpm'].value)
            print(tiername.attributes['diskType'].value)



            if dtype == "5":
                dtype = "FMC"
                #print (poolname.attributes['basicUsableFMCCapacityTotal'].value)
                capKB = poolname.attributes['basicUsableFMCCapacityTotal'].value
                UsedFMC = poolname.attributes['basicUsableFMCCapacityUsed'].value
                FreeKB = int(capKB) - int(UsedFMC)
                FMCUsage = float(UsedFMC)/float(capKB) * 100
                Usage = int(FMCUsage)

            elif dtype == "4":
                dtype = "SAS"
            else:
                dtype = "Unknown"
```

The issue is, eventhough it encounters a pool with no pooltier, it somehoe gets into  'if  dtype == 5" and failing with "KeyError: 'basicUsableFMCCapacityTotal'"

Comment: Have you tried `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: Do you have example code? You want pool/pooltier and pool/pool?

Comment: Every 'Pool' might or might not have 'pooltier".. I need to process "pooltier" if available..else just move on.. Didnt try xml.etree.ElementTree.

Comment: Are you doing `getElementsByTagName` for "pool" followed by `getElementsByTagName` for "pooltier" on those results? That should work.

Comment: If you move to `lxml`, you could do XPATH `"pool/pooltier"`

Comment: I kind of know what is happening, but not sure how to fix it.... The  pooltiers = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PoolTier') is reading from all the 'pool' tags instead of reading only from the current pool